# Elasticsearch. Filtering\search by part of phrase

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I need construct elastic request to search by part of phrase (it must be lowercase search by sequence of words).

For example, record field contains:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam et gubergren vulputate
```

And I need to find this record in next ways (using next search terms):

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem     ipsum dolor
lorem, ipsum.dolor
dolor sit amet
```

Before I used a strict search. My solution was to create a custom analyzer (`Tokenizer = "keyword" and Filter = ["lowercase"]`), add its to field and set field index analyzed while mapping is executing. But now the task changed.

Can anybody help me how to create request? I will be glad even any API elastic reference.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`_analyze` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

By using the noted custom analyzer (`lowercase` `keyword`), you are creating a single, large token:

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=keyword&filters=lowercase&text=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet,+eam+et+gubergren+vulputate'
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam et gubergren vulputate",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 54,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

The only way to find that token is to search for exactly the same (post-analysis if it's being used) token.

However, if you did not use a custom analyzer at all, then you would get these tokens:

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?text=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet,+eam+et+gubergren+vulputate'
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "lorem",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 5,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "ipsum",
         "start_offset": 6,
         "end_offset": 11,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "dolor",
         "start_offset": 12,
         "end_offset": 17,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "sit",
         "start_offset": 18,
         "end_offset": 21,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "amet",
         "start_offset": 22,
         "end_offset": 26,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 5
      },
      {
         "token": "eam",
         "start_offset": 28,
         "end_offset": 31,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 6
      },
      {
         "token": "et",
         "start_offset": 32,
         "end_offset": 34,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 7
      },
      {
         "token": "gubergren",
         "start_offset": 35,
         "end_offset": 44,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 8
      },
      {
         "token": "vulputate",
         "start_offset": 45,
         "end_offset": 54,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 9
      }
   ]
}
```

Now you can search for any word in the "sentence" and find matches, including using the [phrase search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase).

Thinking of it more simply though, you want to search with a `match` query to get the benefits of full text search because it will use the same analyzer on the *search terms*. If you use a `term` query (or filter), then it will only look at the *exact* tokens.

So, without using any custom analyzer at all, then you should be able to use those searches as-is to find the text:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type' -d '{
  "field" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam et gubergren vulputate"
}'
```

By using a [plain `match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query):

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "field" : "lorem, ipsum.dolor"
    }
  }
}'
```